# .net mvc: Does a context's property query filter data from a database into the model object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to follow some online examples of a mvc context. I am trying to understand what happens (in bold) when the context property is accessed in the following line:

Cardata cd = **cdc.cardata.Single(car => car.id == 2)**;

My question is, does the filter act on fields of the database? The reason I ask is when i built the linq query, intellisense seemed to pick up properties of the model object rather than  fields of the database. I assumed you would be filtering database data not the object model data which dosnt exist yet.

Comment: Yes it should query the database, how did you get the suspicion that it queries the object?

Comment: The filter will act on field of the database if they are mapped via a ORM. You didnt tag your question with an ORM so the answer is "it depends".

Comment: Assuming `cdc` is an instance of your context and `cardata` is a `DbSet<Cardata>` property on your context, then yes, this will cause a query roughly akin to (though probably not exactly like): `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Cardatas WHERE id = 2`.

Comment: Hi- I apologize for not tagging properly. I am a new to mvc and do not know what ORM is yet. To answer Ravin. When I hover over id of car.id, id is identified as type int Cardata.id which is a property of my Cardata model class. Chris, from what you said, does linq try to map the model object to the database table? It seems that you build the query from the model perspective and assume linq knows what fields go where.

Comment: PS: Does the names of the database fields have to match the model object's properties? That would clear up some things but it still seems that the query should be built from the database fields because that is the data source.